# How to echo text based on highest number in set of variables?

Tags: php

I am interested in echoing specific text based on which variable in a set of variables, has the greatest numeric value. For example, if `$var1 = 6`, `$var2 = 10`, `$var3 = 8` and `$var4 = 4` I'd like to echo a set of text based on which variable has the highest numerical number. I was looking at another website for PHP Array reference and I saw this code:

```
<?php
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
arsort($age);

foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
     echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
     echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

I was wondering if there was some way I could switch this code around to sort by the variables value.

Note: My variables change throughout due to user interaction.

Comment: Could you store values in an array? What is the text's relation to `varx`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added more information, researched further and edited my post.

Comment: You are sorting by the value when you use `arsort` or do you mean you want to sort by the names rather than the numbers

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am trying to sort by value. As I said in the post, I want to echo text based on which value is sorted highest. I understand how to echo specific text based on which variable is sorted hughest, I just don't know how to sort variables by their values.

Comment: Using arrays is highly recommended. Otherwise, it's a mess of `if`s.

Comment: @Amadan I do have an array with the variables, as I said in a previous comment, I just don't understand how to echo text based on which is sorted highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used `sort()` and `end()` arrays. For reference, here's the code I used:

```
$array = array($var1, $var2, $var3);
sort($array);
if (end($array) == $var1) {
echo "text shown if var1 variable is highest value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
arsort($age);
reset($age); // not needed here, but in general a good idea
$oldest = key($age);
if ($oldest == "Peter") {
  echo "Pete's the boss";
} else {
  echo "Pete's not the boss";
}
```